# how can i make tornado log function work?

Tags: python, tornado

i use this to set my log ,but didn't work.

```
tornado.options.options['log_file_prefix'].set('/opt/logs/my_app.log')
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

got this error

```
    tornado.options.options['log_file_prefix'].set('/logs/my_app.log')
TypeError: 'OptionParser' object is not subscriptable
```

i want the log be printed on both terminal and log files, and i start my application through an xml config file not by the command line directly, how can i do it?

Comment: Can you give more detail of what you are doing especially how you are running the server . Also I think you should mention the tornado version

Comment: this code at the very beginning ,so i don't know how to advance,i use the latest version 3.1.1

Answer (score 5):

Options are generally accessed with attribute syntax instead of item syntax, and you shouldn't call `set()` directly.  To set flags programmatically, use:

```
from tornado.options import options
options.log_file_prefix = "/path/to/log"
```

Tornado uses the standard library `logging` module, so if you want to configure logging just as you'd do in a non-Tornado application you can do that too.  (if you want to use tornado.options for other things but don't want it touching your logging configuration you can set `options.logging = 'none'`)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
from tornado.options import define, options

define("log_file_prefix", default="/opt/logs", help="log file prefix")
```

Comment: this will not work as `log_file_prefix` is already defined by tornado's `define_logging_options`